# How to normalize these tables?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #A
(
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    NUMBER INT,
    ID VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('JOHN', 20,'J10')

+--------+----------+------------+
|NAME    |  NUMBER  |   ID       |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|JOHN    |  20      |   J10      |
|--------|----------|------------|
|MIKE    |  2       |   M5       |
+--------+----------+------------+


CREATE TABLE #B
(
    PRODUCT VARCHAR(10),
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #B 
VALUES ('APPLE', 'JOHN, HARRY'),
       ('ORANGE', 'JOHN,MIKE'),
       ('MANGO', 'JOHN, KATTY, ALEX')


+--------+------------------+
|PRODUCT |NAME              |
+--------+------------------+
|APPLE   |JOHN, HARRY       |
|--------|------------------|
|ORANGE  |JOHN,MIKE         |
+--------+------------------+
|MANGO   |JOHN, KATTY, ALEX |
+--------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Start with first normal form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Tables `#A` and `#B` both need primary keys. The `NAME` column should be removed from `#B` and then add a new "many to many" table with seven rows in it - which is the PK from #A and PK from #B for all of the combinations currently in comma delimited lists

Comment: See [Associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Comment: Note that your many:many join table does not need a separate primary key column. Just make a primary key like this `PRIMARY KEY (A_id, B_id)` And give your tables better names, such as `Person` `Product` `PersonProduct`

Comment: thank you both of you for the answer. Appreciate it. I need help on it. if any one available please msg me in twitter: @nepali_cmt